# Public server acting as proxy to non-public server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

**PROBLEM:** Because my free cloud service is going down, I decided to build my own using RPi and OwnCloud, because it is cheaper and has (basically) unlimited amount of space. I was unable to get public IP address at home, so I bought a simple VPS with public IP.

**WHAT I NEED:** Let's assume, that I have a domain like this: domain.io. I'd like to have my own personal website on that domain and my cloud running on subdomain like cloud.domain.io. Because VPS and servers with huge amount of space are very expensive and I have gigabytes of data, I have to store my data at home at my own server, which makes it much cheaper.

**WHAT I TRIED:** I bought a VPS and RPi. Then I created simple server-client VPN using OpenVPN. Now I am facing the problem - I have to redirect subdomain (aka cloud.domain.io) to my RPi throught that VPN. I would be happy, if I could redirect not only http (https) requests, but all communications - like ssh connections for example. Sadly, I found myself stuck. I wasn't able to find any information about this. I don't even know if anything like this is possible. Any tip would be really welcomed.

Comment: Its not clear what the VPS is for.  Any traffic directed toward the VPN would go to the VPS not the machine assigned the non-static address.

Comment: VPN acts like tunel - becasue RPi doesn't have public IP, I somehow must be able to communicate both ways - from VPS to RPi and backwards. VPS will be used for few other services like email, git and also my personal website.

Comment: Which is my point.  At some point the communication, even if you get it configured, will have to be updated every single time the non-static address changes.

Comment: But VPS has assigned public IP. Adresses in VPN are permanent - until I delete the file in which OpenVPN stores assigned IPs. Since RPi is connects into VPN, which is on that public VPS, where is the problem?

Comment: So is your question how do you configure a subdomain to go to a particular address?

Comment: Yes, but that address is inside VPN.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. Did you ever here of `no ip`? http://www.noip.com/remote-access

Comment: No, I've never heard of this. Pitty I bought that VPS, now I would prefer to find solution on my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. Since IP addresses 10.x.x.x are reserved for NAT and similar stuff, that means, it cannot be assigned from "outside". My VPN has range 10.8.x.x and thus, there is no problem with nginx solution like this:

```
server {
   # other config stuff for subdomain

   location / {
      proxy_pass https://10.8.0.6;
   }
}
```